# why this code hide the whole Div when I use childNodes[x] method?

Tags: dom, removechild, child-nodes

**I want to only hide the P0 paragraph using childNodes[x] . I wonder how it works because it hides the whole div with in this code:**

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="myDiv">
 <p>P0</p>
 <p>P1</p>
</div>

<button onclick="hideFn();">hide</button>

<script>

function hideFn()
    {
      document.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].style.display = "none";

    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You easily could have found the reason yourself by simply doing the traversal step by step:

> document

the document

> .childNodes[0]

the documentElement, also known as the root node (`<html>`)

> .childNodes[1]

the `<body>`

> .childNodes[1]

the `<div>`

Comment: I tell you why I conuld not understand. I understood that the 1st child is <html> which is childNodes[0]. And the 2nd child is <body> and should be childNodes[0] becasue it is the first element inside <html>. And the P0 should be childNodes[1] becase it is the 2nd child of the <body>.......please correct me

Comment: p0 is the child of div. try your browser's debugging tools, they'll show the DOM tree